# Codeigniter - Edit Form with Checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I'm using codeigniter and have a problem with my edit form in checkbox. The checkbox have 2 values 1 and 0, if checked then the value is 1 and if unchecked then the value is 0.

here is my controller:

```
function updatepost($id=0){
    $data = $_POST;
    $this->db->where('id_post',$id);
    $outp = $this->db->update('post',$data);
}
```

And here is my view

```
sport <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="1" <?php if($data['sport'] == '1'){echo 'checked';}?> />

tekno <input type="checkbox" name="tekno" value="1" <?php if($data['tekno'] == '1'){echo 'checked';}?>/>

game <input type="checkbox" name="game" value="1" <?php if($data['game'] == '1'){echo 'checked';}?>/>
```

if i unchecked the checkbox, value should be '0';

My question is how to get value if the checkbox is uncheked?

Many thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller file replace the **$data = $_POST;** line by the following code

```
$data['sport']  = (array_key_exists('sport',$_POST)) ? $_POST['sport'] : 0;
$data['tekno']  = (array_key_exists('tekno',$_POST)) ? $_POST['tekno'] : 0;
$data['game']   = (array_key_exists('game',$_POST)) ? $_POST['game'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes are posted only if they are checked.

In your controller, check if they are posted,

if posted, value is 1 else 0.

Example Code:

```
$sport = 0;
if (! empty($_POST['sport']) {
  $sport = 1;
}
```

If you want to use ternary operators, use:

```
$sport = (! empty($_POST['sport']) ? 1 : 0;
```

So, final code:

```
function updatepost($id=0){
  // Assign default values in view that they are not getting
  // posted if they are not checked.
  // If they are posted, they will be overriden in $data.
  $data['sport'] = $data['tekno'] = $data['tekno'] = 0;
  $data = $_POST;
  $this->db->where('id_post',$id);
  $outp = $this->db->update('post',$data);
}
```

Comment: I try your code but with no success... lets says i have sport value is 1, then in edit form its already checked but i want to change the value into 0, then i uncheked it. And the sport value is still 1